# What are the incidents from old scriptures in which Kshatriyas honored the Brahmins?

Tags: scripture, mahabharata, brahman, varna, kshatriya

In Sanathan dharma, there are four varnas: Brahmin, Kshetriya, Vaishya, and Shudra. It is well known that, in general, Kshatriyas and other orders pay respect, and give honor to Brahmins due to their lifestyle and several other aspects.

One such expression of honor can be seen in the Mahabharatha where Krishna washes the feet of Brahmins during Yudhishthira's Rajasuya

> The eldest of the sons of Pandu, who had been installed at the
> sacrifice, having said this unto all, appointed every one of them to
> suitable offices. He appointed Dussasana to superintend the department
> of food and other enjoyable articles. Aswatthama was asked to attend
> on the Brahmanas. ....Duryyodhana became the receiver of the tributes
> that were brought by the kings. **Krishna who was himself the center of
> all worlds and round who moved every creature, desirous of acquiring
> excellent fruits, was engaged at his own will in washing the feet of
> the Brahmanas.**
>
> [[Section 34, Rajasuyika Parva, Sabha Parva, The Mahabharata]](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m02/m02034.htm)

While mentioning this incident, *Babasaheb Dr. B.R. Ambedkar* expressed his opinion, [as follows](https://www.mea.gov.in/Images/attach/amb/Volume_04.pdf#page=359), in his writing **THE RIDDLE OF RAMA AND KRISHNA**

> In due course the Rajasuya came off. Of the various functions and
> duties connected with the ceremony, Krishna is said to have taken
> charge of washing the feet of the Brahmans. **This is a sure indication
> of the comparative modernness of the Mahabharata, at any rate, of this
> story. For in ancient times, even when the supremacy of the Brahmans
> had been established, the Kshatriyas never paid them any servile
> honor**.

He is claiming that Kshatriyas never paid any servile honor to Brahmins in ancient times.

In this context, I want to know the incidents similar to the one in the first quote, ancient in nature, where Kshatriyas pay servile honor to Brahmins. What are those incidents?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course, a *Dharmika-Kshatriya* would honor a Brahmina.

Since the case of god Sri Krishna is cited in the question, I'm citing the case of god Sri Rama (a Kshatriya again) to attest to this.

### Incident 1:

Rama touches Rishi Agastya's feet.

> Valmiki Ramayana [3.12.24-25](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-ramayana-of-valmiki/d/doc424109.html)
>
> एवम् उक्त्वा महाबाहुः अगस्त्यम् सूर्य वर्चसम् | जग्राह आपतत् **तस्य पादौ
> च रघुनन्दन** || ३-१२-२४
>  अभिवाद्य तु धर्मात्मा तस्थौ **रामः कृतांजलिः** |
> सीतया सह वैदेह्या तदा रामः स लक्ष्मणः || ३-१२-२५
>
> > - 24,25.  **Speaking thus of Agastya, who shone like
> >   the sun, whilst he advanced towards him, the joy of the House of Raghu, Sri Rama, took hold of his feet and paid obeisance to him**. Having saluted him,
> >   **the virtuous Rama stood before him with joined palms**, in company with
> >   Videha’s daughter and Saumitra.

### Incident 2:

All the sages, including Atri and Agastya, arrive at Rama's palace, and Rama honors them with the utmost respect.

> [Valmiki Ramayana 7.1.12-15](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-ramayana-of-valmiki/d/doc424762.html)
>
> श्रुत्वा प्राप्तान्मुनींस्तांस्तु बालसूर्यसमप्रभान् । प्रत्युवाच ततो
> द्वास्स्थं प्रवेशय यथासुखम् ।। ७.१.१२ ।।
> तान् सम्प्राप्तान् मुनीन् दृष्ट्वा प्रत्युत्थाय **कृताञ्जलिः** ।
> **पाद्यार्घ्यादिभिरानर्च गां निवेद्य च सादरम् ।। ७.१.१३ ।।
> रामो ऽभिवाद्य प्रयत आसनान्यादिदेश ह ।** तेषु काञ्चनचित्रेषु महत्सु च
> वरेषु च ।। ७.१.१४ ।।
> कुशान्तर्धानदत्तेषु मृगचर्मयुतेषु च । यथार्हमुपविष्टास्ते
> आसनेष्वृषिपुङ्गवाः ।। ७.१.१५ ।।
>
> > Learning that those ascetics, who resembled the rising sun, had come,
> > Rama said to the door-keeper.
> > “Usher them in with all due respect.”
> > **Thereafter, when the Sages had entered, Rama rose in deference to them
> > and honoured them with water and the Arghya**, bestowing on each a cow.
> > **Then Rama, bowing low, paid obeisance to them and caused raised and
> > costly seats encrusted with gold to be brought,** that were covered with
> > cushions of Kusha Grass and antelope skins, and those mighty Sages
> > seated themselves according to rank and, questioned by Rama concerning
> > their well-being, the great Rishis versed in the Veda, who were
> > accompanied by their disciples, replied to him, saying:—

Comment: Although, there are brahmins in your answer. The context seems to be different. It is not explicit that Rama paid honour due to the Varna.